# Consume a redirected webservice in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, web-services, wsdl

I've been provided a WSDL file that points to a webservice.  I use this webservice to log in and create a session.  In addition to the session token, the login response provides a URL I'm supposed to redirect my webservice calls to.  Other than the URL I'm addressing, the definitions are the same, so no new WSDL is provided.

What is the best way to handle this?  Generate my own altered WSDL?  Create and/or alter the webservice object via Java?  Some third option I've not thought of?

Comment: How are you calling the webservice? Are you using createObject or cfinvoke? Or even CFhttp?

Comment: I'm calling the webservice by calling CFOBJeCT on a locally-stored WSDL file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hack, but you can always download the WSDL as a template, and reference it as a local file. When the login call tells you what URL to hit, simply replace the URL in the template with the new one, and proceed. You could even have a different version of the WSDL for each URL that could be returned,  maybe using a hash of the URL as the filename.

Comment: Yeah.  That's more or less what I meant by "Generate my own altered WSDL".  That's proabbly what I'll end up doing.

Comment: Oh, and I'll set this as "answered" once I have an implementation in place, unless someone comes up with something better.

Answer (score 0):

Coldfusion webservice invocations always point to WSDL.  Be it a local WSDL file, or a remote WSDL file you can access over an HTTP or HTTPs connection.  Unless the responding URL points to a new WSDL file to use, it's not going to be that helpful.

-Jay